# Requesting data access for my domain installed Google Apps Script webapp

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a little inhouse webapp I'm attempting to deploy to my Google Apps Domain as an authorized, preinstalled app for all users.  I can install the app without too much trouble, but the data access levels the app asks for are very basic.  The app then appears in the list installed domain apps for my users, but they need to click it and authorize it personally before it runs.  I know it's possible to configure a webapp to add these authorization levels when installed by the domain admin, but I can't seem to find the documentation on how to do this.  Usually I authorize my app in doGet thusly:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('newer_than:1d');
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(
     "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmotaW2MiedTdDNPS09OMFo0UGc3S2FTYThoSl9pUHc&usp=sharing");
```

Which grants the required GMail and Sheets access on installation.  The domain installation process seems to ignore this though.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: its not possible as you have written it, because that is done with server-to-server oauth2, not with the 3-legged (from client) oauth that apps script supports. you would need to 1. ensure all the apis you use support impersonation of gapps domain  users, and 2. use custom code from apps script to manually do the 2-step oauth2 with a service account.

Comment: Hmm, but other Apps I've seen in the Marketplace successfully request the right levels of access to my user's accounts when I add them to the domain.  How are they doing it?

Comment: you, the domain superadmin, gave permission to an app which then stored the token on a server that later uses it with 2-step oauth2

Comment: Yup, understood.  But the access levels my app requests from the domain aren't the same as those it requests when a user executes it.